# What is the best way to test cover a method that just call another method?

Tags: java, testing, junit, test-coverage

What is the best way to test or ignore coverage of the following method? Notice that the update method just calls the service and I must cover 80% of the class/code.

[image]

Comment: since there is no actual logic here, i don't think this needs to be tested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two answers.

- If you need the `update` method to be covered by your tests, simply write a (unit) test that calls it.  (It shouldn't be difficult.)  This would be my recommendation.
- By inspection, you *could* conclude that the method is trivial and doesn't need to be tested.  You may be able to exclude it from the test coverage<sup>1</sup>.  Alternatively, you could "solve" this by finding some other non-covered code, and writing tests to cover that code ... to boost the overall coverage to the required 80%.

But the flipside is that this method is not completely trivial.  If for some reason `userService` is `null`, this method will raise an NPE.  Maybe some test cases are needed for picking up cases where `userService` hasn't been configured correctly.

And while the current implementation of `update` seems trivial, someone might modify the method in the future to do something more complicated.  Simply calling it may pick up (future) problems that wouldn't otherwise be noticed.

---

<sup>1 - It will depend on the coverage tool you use.  You haven't mentioned what that is.</sup>